# xrandr -off doesn't disable disable display

Tags: xrandr

What else could I do in order to disable the unused internal notebook display

Get displays

`$ xrandr -q | grep -e " connected"`

```
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 280mm x 160mm
DP2 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
```

Disable internal

`$ xrandr --output LVDS1 --off --verbose`

```
crtc 1: disable
screen 0: 3840x2160 1001x563 mm  97.34dpi
```

Yet it remains on

`$ xrandr -q | grep -e " connected"`

```
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 280mm x 160mm
DP2 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
```

Comment: Try this `xrandr --output LVDS1 --off --output DP2 --left-of LVDS1 --auto`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thx. Can't notice any change.

Comment: You could file a bug report. 

Intel: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/wikis/How-to-file-i915-bugs
AMD: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues
NVIDIA: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-unix-graphics/linux/148